# Passing multiple parameters to docker container

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to pass 2 parameters to a docker container for a dash app (via a shell script). Passing one parameter works, but two doesn't. Here's what happens when I pass two parameters:

command:

```
sudo sh create_dashboard.sh 6 4
```

Error:

```
creating docker
Running for parameter_1: 6 
Running for parameter_2: 4 
usage: app.py [-h] [-g parameter_1] [-v parameter_2]
app.py: error: argument -g/--parameter_1: expected one argument
```

The shell script:

```
echo "creating docker"
docker build -t dash-example .
echo "Running for parameter_1: $1 "
echo "Running for parameter_2: $2 "
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 --memory=10g dash-example $1 $2
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app
COPY src/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY src /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "app.py", "-g", "-v"]
```

When I use this command:

```
sudo sh create_dashboard.sh 6
```

the docker container runs perfectly, with parameter_2 being None.

Comment: Your entrypoint does not match the syntax of your command line application. Drop the `-g` and `-v` from it and add both arguments including the value to the actual call.

Comment: You can try `docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 sh -c "--memory=10g dash-example $1 $2"`.

Comment: @lewislbr This is the new error: ```Running for parameter_1: 6

Running for parameter_2: 4

Unable to find image 'sh:latest' locally

docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sh, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.```

Comment: @KlausD. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: My bad, it would be `docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 dash-example sh -c "--memory=10g dash-example $1 $2"`.

Comment: Glad to help! I'll add the comment as an answer so people will be able to see the solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a command into the shell of a container like this:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 dash-example sh -c "--memory=10g dash-example $1 $2"
```

So it allows arguments and any other command.

Answer (score 0):

When you `docker run ... dash-example $1 $2`, the additional parameters are interpreted as the "command" the container should run.  Since your image has an `ENTRYPOINT`, the words of the command are just tacked on to the end of the words of the entrypoint (see [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation).  There's no way to cause the words of one command to be interspersed with the words of another; you are effectively getting a command line of

```sh
python app.py -g -v 6 4
```

The approach I'd recommend here is to not use an `ENTRYPOINT` at all.  Make sure you can directly run the application script (its first line should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, it should be executable) and make the image's default `CMD` be to run the script:

```sh
FROM python:3.9
...
# RUN chmod +x app.py  # if needed
# no ENTRYPOINT at all
CMD ["./app.py"]       # finds "python" via the shebang line
```

Then your wrapper can supply a complete command line, including the options you need to run:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 --memory=10g dash-example \
  ./app.py -g "$1" -v "$2"
```

(There is an alternate "container as command" pattern, where the `ENTRYPOINT` contains the command to run and the `CMD` its options.  This can lead to awkward `docker run --entrypoint` command lines for routine debugging tasks, and if the command itself is short it doesn't really save you a lot.  You'd still need to repeat the `-g` and `-v` options in the wrapper.)